# Gaming and 1080p video stutter

Tags: graphics-card, display-driver

After I installed nVidia 368.22 driver (365.19 previous) I started having random stuttering in games and 1080p video. Games can be fixed with alt-tab. Sometimes after stuttering in video I get the `display driver stopped responding ...` message.

Now comes the weird part - I uninstalled 368.22, cleaned with DDU, installed 365.19 and the problem is still there, although I had no problems whatsoever with 365.19 before I installed 368.22 and I have made no other hardware/software changes.

System Details:

- OS: Windows 10 x64
- Motherboard: MSI G45-Z87
- CPU: i7-4770K
- RAM: Geil 2x8GB 2133 RAM
- Graphics: MSI GTX970 SLI
- Storage: Samsung 250GB 850evo, 250GB 840 SSD, Seagate 1TB HDD
- Power Supply: Corsair RM1000W

Edit: Well, something did fix it but I have no idea what exactly, because I tried a lot of stuff. Anyway not installing 368.22 again.

Comment: Can you disable SLI and confirm that each video card works to 100% independently?

Comment: Yes, they do, stutter is still there though.

Comment: Aside from being up-to-date, do you have compatibility reasons for needing to use 368.22?

Comment: No, but after installing it the issue is there even with the older driver.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please try downloading the driver manually from the link provided below and perform custom (clean) installation in Safe Mode.
   http://www.nvidia.in/Download/driverResults.aspx/103097/en-in
2. Please install GPU-Z from the link provided below and check the sensor tab for possible heating.
   https://www.techpowerup.com/downloads/2699/techpowerup-gpu-z-v0-8-8
3. Update your system with all the latest drivers and windows update.
4. Disable any anti-virus/firewall program which might be running
5. Disable V-Sync, either globally from NVIDIA control panel or within game to test FPS.
6. Disable SLI setup and test the performance on a single card.
7. If you did not install anything important recently, restore your system to the point of time when you were not facing this issue.

Comment: Check in NVCPL if the Physx processor is set to GPU
Go to Nvidia Control Panel -> Managed 3D Settings -> Power Management Mode: Prefer Maximum Performance

Answer (score 0):

Try playing at lower settings. See if problem persists.

Restore windows and nvcp profiles.

Check if this works.

I never update nvidia drivers, I knew this happens. And its very frustrating.

Zotac GTX 970-4GB / i7-4790k /16Gb RAM.